# how to post an ajax call and C# to recognize child objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dhtml

The code works except for receiving the child collection of addresses?  What is the correct way to send this collection in json?  unfortunately this attempt fails.  The 'addresses' value is null
Thanks,

```
var val = {
    'forename': 'test',
    'surname': 'test',
    'postcode': 'test',
    'Addresses': {
        'Line1': 'Test',
        'Line2': 'Here'
    }
};

jr.ajax.loadJson(url, val,
   true,
   function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   }, 
   true, 'post', val);
});


// I want the posted value to be this object

public class Member
{
    public string forename { get; set; }        
    public string surname { get; set; }        
    public string postcode { get; set; }
    public Address[] Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }        
    public string Line2 { get; set; }        
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Show(Member request) {..}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is incorrect for your Addresses child member.

In your model, you have Addresses as an array of addresses.  However, in your JSON, you're sending Addresses as a single address.  That won't work.

Instead, change your JSON to be:

```
var val = {
    'forename': 'test',
    'surname': 'test',
    'postcode': 'test',
    'Addresses': [
        {
            'Line1': 'Test',
            'Line2': 'Here'
        }
    ]
};
```

Note the `[` and `]` around the address structure.  This should now work.

One additional consideration is to use `List<Address>` instead of `Address[]` in your model.